# Getting response data out of Fetch blob from Wikipedia api

Tags: javascript, fetch, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to use Wikipedia's api with fetch.

```
const endpoint = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
action=query&format=json&origin=*&titles=Albert%20Einstein'

 fetch(endpoint)
          .then(blob => blob.json())
          .then(data => console.log(data))
```

RETURNS

[image]

I'm not sure how to drill down in this, due to that `736`. I assume there is nothing there? What do these results mean?

I did these loops to see if they allowed me something I could not get by clicking in the console. It's the same as fetch call above so not really useful. Just wanted to show that I tried something at least (downvote control).

```
fetch(endpoint)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then((data) => {
    for(var i in data){
     //returns batch complete ,
      //& query
      for(var j in data.query){ 
         //returns pages
        for(var k in data.query.pages){
        //returns the string 736
        }
      }
  }
  })
```

Does nothing more than clicking the console results above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `formatversion=2` for a slightly more comfortable format (where `data.query.pages` is an array).

Alternatively, you could iterate the object with something like

```
var pages = data.query.pages;
for (pageId in pages) {
    if (pages.hasOwnProperty(pageId)) {
        console.log(pages[pageId]);
    }
}
```

In modern browsers you can also use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the properties of the object in an array.

Comment: Turns out the response data was a very small object, and this mislead me to think it was an error. Nonetheless, your advice on how to dig down and get the `data.query.pages` as an array was very helpful. It was the only way I could get the data out of the fetch request. 
```var results = []
    fetch(endpoint)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then((data) => {
      var pages = data.query.pages
      pages.forEach(i=> results.push(i))
     })
console.log(results)```